# Download file on a wearable app

Tags: android, wear-os

I created a little app on my Moto360 smartwtach to play audio content downloaded from a web server. I used the following code snippet to download the content from a given URL.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Downloading file !!!");
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error on http connection !! ");
            return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
        }

        // this will be useful to display download percentage
        // might be -1: server did not report the length
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            // allow canceling with back button
            if (isCancelled()) {
                input.close();
                return null;
            }
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception : " + e);
        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "download finished!");
                output.close();
            }
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I get a timeout connection :

```
08-06 16:22:06.345  17925-17941/com.example.ile14017.moto360 E/DownloadTask﹕ exception : java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to api.europe1.fr/85.116.42.56 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

I tried to change the connection timeout value (setConnectTimeout method) but the result is the same. The size of the file to download is about 2Mo.

Comment: For downloading tasks you can use Android `DownloadManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) instead to programm it yourself. A pretty tutorial can be found on:
http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-the-downloadmanager-to-manage-your-downloads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your watch connected (via BT) to your phone? If so, then your watch doesn't have a wifi connectivity to use URLConnection to make a network call even if the wifi is set up on the watch. You need to consider that case and use your phone to do the download for you and then transfer the file to your watch using, say, the ChannelApi.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't check if the Wi-Fi was enabled on my watch, and it wasn't! I had to update it, but it works fine now, thanks!